# d3 giveing error of unexpect token on import

Tags: d3.js

error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Sawai\Desktop\Blended\wallet\node_modules\d3-array\dist\d3-array.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (139:6)

```
var sum = 0, index = 0;
  138 |   return Float64Array.from(values, valueof === undefined
> 139 |     ? v => (sum += +v || 0)
      |       ^
  140 |     : v => (sum += +valueof(v, index++, values) || 0));
```

My version :

```
"d3": "^6.7.0",
"@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.14.5",
```

Comment: the same here :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have reported that problem to the project upstream, lets wait for their response:

- https://github.com/d3/d3-array/issues/229
- https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3527

Update: So the problem is with Babel compiler, not really the `d3`/`d3-array.cmsusm()` although they use some wild syntax, this should be fixed with https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/13581.